# Recorrer input con jquery

Tags: jquery, each

quiero realizar lo siguiente:
Bloquear(disabled) los **dos primeros inputs** y ademas agregar el "-" si es que el **tercero contiene un "-"**. Todo esto al recibir el foco en el primer input de la fila.
Lo que realicé me bloquea todos los input, incluso los de la segunda fila.
Soy algo novato en esto, espero haberme explicado bien, gracias.

```js
$('.blk').focus(function(){
  $('.blk').each(function(){
    if($('.porcentaje').val() == "-"){
      $(this).val("-");
      $(this).prop("disabled", true);
      $('.otro').val("-");
      $('.otro').prop("disabled", true);
    }
   }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="blk">
<input type="text" class="otro">
<input type="text" value="-" disabled class="porcentaje"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="blk">
<input type="text" class="otro">
<input type="text" value="10" disabled class="porcentaje">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer lo que quieres no necesitas usar la función `each()` para recorrer todos los `<input>`. Explico lo que hace cada línea con los comentarios dentro del código, que creo que quedará más claro.

```js
//La función la lanzará el hacerle focus a un elemento con la clase "blk"
$('.blk').focus(function(){
  
  //Comprobamos si el tercer elemento (el siguiente del siguiente al que lanzó el evento), tiene como value '-'
  if ($(this).next().next().val() === '-') { //Si lo tiene...
    //El value del primer elemento pasa a ser '-'
    $(this).val('-');
    
    //El value del segundo elemento pasa a ser '-'
    $(this).next().val('-');
    
    //Desactivamos el primer input (el que lanza el evento)
    $(this).prop('disabled', true); 
    
    //Desactivamos el segundo (el siguiente elemento hermano al que lanza el evento)
    $(this).next().prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="blk">
<input type="text" class="otro">
<input type="text" value="-" disabled class="porcentaje"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="blk">
<input type="text" class="otro">
<input type="text" value="10" disabled class="porcentaje">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, estaba demasiado cerrado con la idea del each()

Comment: ¡Un placer! Hasta los expertos necesitan a veces un punto de vista diferente para salir del atolladero ;)

Comment: he vuelto a ejecutar tu solución y no me funciona, y al aplicarla a mi proyecto tampoco esta funcionando :/

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no te funciona? ¿Algún mensaje de error en la consola del navegador? ¿Tienes la misma estructura HTML que has puesto en el ejemplo? El código que se ejecuta aquí parece funcionar, ¿qué ves que falla?